# Why does it take 2 clicks to open a popup model + it displays the previous result first then the actual result

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I am creating a search functionality which looks at the Active Directory and get the user info. The querying of Active directory and everything is working fine. but, when i try to display it after clicking on a button, it requires me to click twice. And even after that, i change my search fields, on first click it display first result, and then clicking the second time displays the new result.

I am new to javascript and MVC and do not know how to figure it out.

Javascript Codes are as follows:

$(document).ready(function () {

```
        var url = '@Url.Action("GetMenu","Test")';
        $('#openBtn').click(function (event) {
            var search = $('#searchAttr').val();
            $('#searchresults').load(url, { search: search });
        });
```

}

where i am passing the search keyword into a controller class Getmenu in Test controller.

```
 public ActionResult GetMenu(string search)
        {
                //get a list of Active Users and pass it in partial view.
                //getting active users works fine
                return PartialView("_Test", lstADUsers);

            }
            catch (System.Exception e)
            {
                throw new Exception("Error authenticating user." + e.Message);
            }          
        }
```

and in my partial view i have a modal to display the resutls.

```
@model List<string>
<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.11.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.11.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/bootstrap.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/custom.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/myScripts.js"></script>

<div class="modal fade" id="myModal">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
                <h3 class="modal-title">Big Title</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <h5 class="text-center">Hello. Some text here.</h5>

                <table class="table table-striped" id="tblGrid">
                    <thead id="tblHead">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Name</th>
                            <th>Email</th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>

                        @for (int item = 0; item < Model.Count; item = item + 2)
                        {
                            <tr>

                                <td style="width: 300px">
                                    @Model[item].ToString()
                                </td>

                                @{ int temp = item;
                                    item = item + 1;
                                }
                                <td style="width: 100px">
                                    @Model[item].ToString()
                                </td>
                                @{
                                    item = temp;
                                }
                            </tr>
                                    }
                    </tbody>
                </table>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <input type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm pull-right" value="Reset">
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default " data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
            </div>

        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Please, i am really stuck and would really appreciate it if anyone could help me solve this.

Comment: Would really really appreciate if anyone can answer that

Comment: Use [CallBack Function](http://api.jquery.com/load/) for load and see what results it is returning on each click by debugging it. And try to empty existing contents from your `searchresults` - `$('#searchresults').empty().load(url, { search: search });`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but when i write the codes you suggested, the popup does not show anyway... i have debugged it and see that the controller class is called and the data is saved in the list, but the pop up does not happen thus no data displayed.